# Kafka poor performance

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka in order to send camera frames from one pc to another. Each frame is around 900KB.

The problem is that when using Kafka, sending a frame takes around 2.5 seconds, while it only takes around 0.5 seconds when using other pub-sub solutions, such as MQTT. I have tried tinkering with various Kafka settings, such as compression and even segmenting the frames but nothing seems to improve the performance.

Any suggestions to improve the performance will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you suspect that the problem is related to code?

Comment: No, I think it has to do with the Kafka configuration.

Comment: Have you checked `batch.size` and `linger.ms` on producer side?